# how to open vs2012 project solution to vs2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have develop project in visual studio 2012 , but now im trying to open that project in visual studio 2010?its showing error like cant open the solution

Comment: What is the exact error? What kind of project?

Answer (score 1):

In your .sln file, open with notepad and...

Change the:

Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00

To:

Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00